# Unable to get or display received sms using plivo token and auth id in php

Tags: php, api, sms, plivo

I'm working on the PHP script where I want to get and display all message which is received on the plivo number?

I have already tried two different methods which are not working

Please guide how do I get the `your_message_uuid` which is necessary in Method 1?

**Method 1**

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Plivo\RestClient;

$client = new RestClient("auth id", "auth_token");
$response = $client->messages->get('your_message_uuid');
print_r($response);
```

**Method 2**

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Plivo\RestClient;

$client = new RestClient("auth id", "auth_token");
$response = $client->messages->list(
    [
        'limit' => 5,
        'offset' => 0,
        'subaccount' =>'subaccount_auth_id'
    ]
);
print_r($response);
// Prints only the message_uuid
print_r($response->getmessageUuid(0));
```

**Result Using Method 1**

```
Plivo\Resources\Message\Message Object ( [client:protected] => Plivo\BaseClient Object ( [timeout:protected] => [httpClientHandler:protected] => Plivo\HttpClients\PlivoGuzzleHttpClient Object ( [guzzleClient:protected] => GuzzleHttp\Client Object ( [config:GuzzleHttp\Client:private] => Array ( [handler] => GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack Object ( [handler:GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack:private] => Closure Object ( [static] => Array ( [default] => GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler Object ( [factory:GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler:private] => GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory Object ( [handles:GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory:private] => Array ( ) [maxHandles:GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory:private] => 50 ) [selectTimeout:GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler:private] => 1 [active:GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler:private] => [handles:GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler:private] => Array ( ) [delays:GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler:private] => Array ( ) [options:GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler:private] => Array ( ) ) [sync] => GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler Object ( [factory:GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler:private] => GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory Object ( [handles:GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory:private] => Array ( [0] => Resource id #55 ) [maxHandles:GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory:private] => 3 ) ) ) [parameter] => Array ( [$request] => [$options] => ) ) [stack:GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack:private] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Closure Object ( [parameter] => Array ( [$handler] => ) ) [1] => http_errors ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Closure Object ( [parameter] => Array ( [$handler] => ) ) [1] => allow_redirects ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Closure Object ( [parameter] => Array ( [$handler] => ) ) [1] => cookies ) [3] => Array ( [0] => Closure Object ( [parameter] => Array ( [$handler] => ) ) [1] => prepare_body ) ) [cached:GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack:private] => Closure Object ( [static] => Array ( [handler] => GuzzleHttp\RedirectMiddleware Object ( [nextHandler:GuzzleHttp\RedirectMiddleware:private] => Closure Object ( [static] => Array ( [handler] => GuzzleHttp\PrepareBodyMiddleware Object ( [nextHandler:GuzzleHttp\PrepareBodyMiddleware:private] => Closure Object ( [static] => Array ( [default] => GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler Object ( [factory:GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler:private] => GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory Object ( [handles:GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory:private] => Array ( ) [maxHandles:GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory:private] => 50 ) [selectTimeout:GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler:private] => 1 [active:GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler:private] => [handles:GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler:private] => Array ( ) [delays:GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler:private] => Array ( ) [options:GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler:private] => Array ( ) ) [sync] => GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler Object ( [factory:GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler:private] => GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory Object ( [handles:GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory:private] => Array ( [0] => Resource id #55 ) [maxHandles:GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory:private] => 3 ) ) ) [parameter] => Array ( [$request] => [$options] => ) ) ) ) [parameter] => Array ( [$request] => [$options] => ) ) ) ) [parameter] => Array ( [$request] => [$options] => ) ) ) [allow_redirects] => Array ( [max] => 5 [protocols] => Array ( [0] => http [1] => https ) [strict] => [referer] => [track_redirects] => ) [http_errors] => 1 [decode_content] => 1 [verify] => 1 [cookies] => [idn_conversion] => 1 [headers] => Array ( [User-Agent] => GuzzleHttp/6.5.5 curl/7.75.0 PHP/7.2.34 ) ) ) [authId:protected] =>  [authToken:protected] =>  ) [basicAuth:protected] => Plivo\Authentication\BasicAuth Object ( [authId:protected] => [authToken:protected] => ) ) [interface:protected] => [id:protected] => [pathParams:protected] => Array ( [authId] => [messageUuid] => ) [properties] => Array ( [from] => [to] => [messageDirection] => [messageState] => [messageTime] => [messageType] => [messageUuid] => [resourceUri] => [totalAmount] => [totalRate] => [units] => ) )
```

**Empty Result Using Method 2**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Plivo's use case guide to receiving SMS messages](https://www.plivo.com/docs/sms/use-cases/receive-sms/). It explains how to

1. create a PHP app to read the message content
2. create a Plivo SMS app and assign the PHP app to it
3. assign the Plivo SMS app to a Plivo number (that will receive the
   incoming SMS messages)
4. whenever an incoming SMS message is received on that Plivo number, Plivo
   will send the details to his app server configured in the Plivo SMS
   app (message URL)